# Output email plugin logstash

Tags: logstash

Hi there i want to use email plugin.i get this error:

```
Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Couldn't find any output plugin named 'email'
```

this is pipeline.conf:

```
output {
if  "ERROR" in [LEVEL]
{
elasticsearch {
  hosts=>"localhost:9200"
  }
  }
  email {
        options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.gmail.com",
         "port", "587",
         "userName", "user",
         "password", "mypassword",
         "authenticationType", "plain",
         "starttls","true"
           ]
            from => "transmitter"
            subject => "logstash alert"
            to => "receiver"
            via => "smtp"
            body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
       }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

The `email` plugin is not installed by default, so you will have to run:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-email
```

Comment: Thanks @fylie ,it works now.but i get an other error like below:

Something happen while delivering an email {:exception=>#<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Connection refused.
This is pipeline.conf:
output {
 email {
  to => "receiver"
  address => "localhost"
  codec => "plain"
  contenttype => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  via => "smtp"
  port => 25
  domain => "localhost"
  from => "logstash.alert@nowhere.com"
  subject => "Test"
  use_tls => false

  }
}

Comment: Does `telnet localhost 25` connect?

Comment: no doesn't connect: Connexion à smtp-server.domain.com...Impossible d’ouvrir une connexion à l’hôte, sur le port 25: Échec lors de la connexion

Comment: Then that's why you're getting an error.... your pipeline config is trying to connect to something that doesn't exist.